# Clang compilation error on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

This problem seems to only be present on MacOS, compilation is fine on linux also using clang.

the following code is a simplification but demonstrates the issue,

```
#include<iostream>
int index = 0;
int main()
{
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
}
```

throws this error on compilation:

```
    main.cpp:2:5: error: redefinition of 'index' as different kind of symbol
int index = 0;
    ^
/usr/include/strings.h:73:7: note: previous definition is here
char    *index(const char *, int) __POSIX_C_DEPRECATED(200112L);
         ^
main.cpp:5:18: warning: address of function 'index' will always evaluate to
      'true' [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
              ~~ ^~~~~
main.cpp:5:18: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
                 ^
                 &
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

These were the compiler arguments used:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test
```

when removing iostream with stdio or nothing the code compiles as expected. Is their a way to fix this or will I have to rename my variable to avoid this?

I did find [this](https://github.com/cs50/checks/issues/5) but I am already using the C++11 flag and the -std=c11 flag doesn't seem to be valid for C++ code.

Comment: Why do you expect it to compile?

Comment: What do you think `index` is?

Comment: Made a careless typo index should be the name not the type.

Comment: You are obviously re-typing the code - don't do that - post it using copy and paste.

Comment: Code and error message don't match.  Please post the real error from the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific version of clang/xcode you're using happens to include the `<strings.h>` header when you include `<iostream>`. `<strings.h>` provides a function called `index()` at global scope. Thus, you cannot declare a variable also at global scope with the same name.

Either rename the variable, or move it into `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int index = 0;
    std::cout << index << std::endl;
}
```

This works because when a variable has the same identifier as something else but is in a different scope, it is considered a different entity altogether.

To give you an example on how that works, consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int myVar = 0;

int main()
{
    int myVar = 1;
    std::cout << myVar << '\n';
    std::cout << ::myVar << '\n';
}
```

This will print:

```
1
0
```

because `myVar` refers to the local variable, but `::myVar` to the one at global scope.

Comment: Are their versions or Xcode/clang that don't contain strings.h? From the search results I've found it seems like its a default header in Macs. I'm currently using Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)

Comment: @ErikW No idea. In any event, it's not something you can control. So either use a different name, move the variable to another scope, or use a namespace as pointed out by Caleb in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is their a way to fix this or will I have to rename my variable to avoid this?

C++ provides namespaces specifically to avoid collisions between names. You can create one for your variable:

```
#include<iostream>

namespace MyGlobals {
    int index = 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyGlobals::index << std::endl;
}
```